# Retrieve argument type uniqueidentifier

Tags: uniqueidentifier, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have in SQL Anywhere following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "documents" (
    "doc_id" uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(*),
    "doc_description" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY("doc_id")
)
```

I created a Datawindow.

(SQL Statement:

```
SELECT
"documents"."doc_id",      
"documents"."doc_description"
FROM "documents"   
WHERE "documents"."doc_id" = :ruid_doc )
```

I added `ruid_doc` as a retrieval argument and type = string.

When i try to save,  I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE = 07006 
>   [Sybase][ODBC Driver] Cannot convert 0 to uniqueidentifier.

I have tried to use `convert` and `cast`.

fyi it is possible to do this via edit source.

Comment: What version of SQL Anywhere are you using? There were significant changes in 9.0.2. Also your PowerBuilder version.

Comment: SQL Anywhere 9.0.2.3000 and PowerBuilder 10.5 Build 4523

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/powerbuilder/blog/2012/10/25/using-autoincrementing-columns-from-a-powerbuilder-datawindow) describing how to use an autoincremented column in a datawindow may help.

In short:

- in the DW you declare the column as numeric
- in the update properties of the DW, select the correct column for the the "identity column"
- depending on the DBMS used, you need to tell in the `PBODBxxx.ini` (xxx being the version number) how an identity column is retrieved after insert. As it seems that you are using a Sybase driver, it can be

  ```
  [Sybase SQL Server]
  PBSyntax='SYBASE_SYNTAX'
  ```

  and

  ```
  [SYBASE_SYNTAX]
  GetIdentity='Select @@identity'
  ; GetIdentity='Select max(IDENTCOL) from &TableName'
  ; Alternative technique if table has insert trigger associated with it.
  ```

The post explains it in full details.

Comment: fyi: UNIQUEIDENTIFIER values generated using NEWID can therefore be used as keys in a **synchronization environment**. Your post is describing how to retrieve autoincremented column data in pb environment.

Comment: @KostasL: So? I am afraid I that I do not see difference between the two. Beware that the pbodb.ini file is used both during design time with the PB IDE and with the final application.

Comment: :My problem consists in how to create a datawindow when I have as primary key value an UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and when I want to retrieve a specific column, but what you are describing is something else entirely.